ROS2 Humble - Can't find libgazebo_ros_factory.so after installing ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkgs
Running ROS2 Humble in conda via RoboStack. I have installed ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkg but see no evidence of libgazebo_ros_init.so or  libgazebo_ros_factory.so installed on my machine.
Assuming this is the root cause of my gazebo spawner node failing via gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py and returning:
[INFO] [1723503078.578469654] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[INFO] [1723503078.579020789] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[INFO] [1723503078.585026898] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[INFO] [1723503078.588259124] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[INFO] [1723503078.588627589] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[ERROR] [1723503108.975306091] [spawn_entity]: Service %s/spawn_entity unavailable. Was Gazebo started with GazeboRosFactory?
[ERROR] [1723503108.978652402] [spawn_entity]: Spawn service failed. Exiting.

Attempting to run:
gzserver --verbose -s libgazebo_ros_init.so  
Returns:
 [Err] [Plugin.hh:212] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_init.so: dlopen(libgazebo_ros_init.so, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/miniconda3/envs/ros2_humble/opt/rviz_ogre_vendor/lib/libgazebo_ros_init.so' (no such file), '/libgazebo_ros_init.so' (no such file), '/opt/miniconda3/envs/ros2_humble/lib/gazebo-11/plugins/libgazebo_ros_init.so' (no such file), '/libgazebo_ros_init.so'
Similar output for libgazebo_ros_factory.so
I would assume these files would be in:
/opt/miniconda3/envs/ros2_humble/lib/gazebo-11/plugins
However I have not found evidence of these files being installed anywhere on my machine, hence I believe this is not a path our sourcing issue.
Is there another package I should be installing for these dependencies?

I encountered a similar issue when running:
gzserver --verbose -s libgazebo_ros_init.so

I received an error message like:
[Err] [Plugin.hh:212] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_init.so: dlopen(libgazebo_ros_init.so, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/*redacted*/lib/libgazebo_ros_init.so' (no such file),
Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_init.dylib: dlopen(libgazebo_ros_init.dylib, 0x0009): Library not loaded: @rpath/libprotobuf.25.1.0.dylib

The issue was related to a version mismatch in the protobuf library. I had 25.1.0 installed and the expected version was 25.2.0. I resolved it by creating a symbolic link for the expected library version. Here’s what I did:
cd /Users/*redacted*/Public/miniforge3/envs/ros_env/lib
ln -s libprotobuf.25.2.0.dylib libprotobuf.25.1.0.dylib

This pointed the expected library name to the correct version that was installed.
You might want to check if there’s a similar version mismatch or missing library in your setup.
